# Como modificar un dato de una columna solo si dicha columna existe Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

Quiero hacer que cuando se modifique una fila en una tabla, el momento en el que se actualizó se guarde en una columna llamada f_oper.
Basado en esta pregunta de SO en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426656/track-last-modification-timestamp-of-a-row-in-postgres y viendo como funciona un trigger, conseguí crear este ejemplo mínimo y verificable:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prueba(row INTEGER, f_oper DATE);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prueba2(row INTEGER);

INSERT INTO prueba(row) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO prueba2(row) VALUES (1);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.f_oper = NOW();
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_timestamp ON prueba;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS set_timestamp ON prueba2;

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON prueba
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON prueba2
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();
```

El problema está en que la primera tabla tiene la columna `f_oper`, pero la segunda no, lo que causa un error. Mi pregunta es, ¿Cuál es el condicional adecuado para evitar el error?¿Y cómo pongo un condicional en una función?

Perdonen por lo basica que es mi segunda pregunta, es mi primera vez en el mundo de las funciones y triggers en Postgresql.

Comment: puedes explicar el caso de uso? es para correr un script que genere los triggers sin tener certeza del schema en ese instante?

Comment: @ffflabs En realidad si tengo certeza del schema, pero me parece mejor no crear una función diferente por cada tabla. Así que supongo que la respuesta a tu pregunta sería sí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi opinión esto es igual que crear un índice en una columna que no existe: lo mejor es no hacerlo más que construir lógica alrededor de algo tan estructural.

Como sea, sí es posible usando excepciones. No sé qué tanto sea la penalización de performance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.f_oper = NOW();
    RETURN NEW;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN undefined_column THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(aunque en realidad no necesitas especificar que sólo te interesa esa excepción. Le puedes poner: `WHEN others THEN...` para manejar todas las excepciones del trigger

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, tienes razón. Esto afectaría la velocidad de la base de datos. No se por que no lo pensé, pero me costo 50 de reputación. La próxima seré más atento. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, recibirás la reputación en cuanto me deje el foro c: